# The requested URL was not found on this server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, twig, silex

I'm trying to create a website with Twig and Silex but I get a `404 Not Found` error when I want access to `/test` page.

`http://127.0.0.1/public_html/M1-CSI/web/` works.

`http://127.0.0.1/public_html/M1-CSI/web/test` doesn't works.

#### .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options -MultiViews

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Routing file

```
<?php

$routes = $app['controllers_factory'];

$routes->get('/', 'Sources\\Controllers\\ExempleController::exemple');
$routes->get('/test', 'Sources\\Controllers\\ExempleController::test');

return $routes;
```

#### Controller

```
<?php

namespace Sources\Controllers;

use \Silex\Application;

class ExempleController {

    public function exemple(Application $app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('exemple.html.twig', array('exempleValue' => 3));
    }

    public function test(Application $app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('test.html.twig');
    }

}
```

Thank's a lot.

## EDIT

You can find source code extract here : https://github.com/nlamblin/website-boilerplate

## SOLUTION

Problem solved.

I added these code lines :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
</Directory>
```

in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Comment: Did you mount the factory?

Comment: I have this code line in boostrap.php :  `$app->mount('/', include BASE_DIRECTORY_PROJECT . '/app/config/routes.php');`

Comment: Ok where did you put your `index` file? I figure you've put it outside the web folder? Then you need to add `RewriteBase web` to your `.htaccess` (could be that it's need to be `/web`) [reference](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/web_servers.html)

Comment: `index.php` is into `/web` folder. Add `Rewrite Base web` or `Rewrite Base /web` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Don't use Silex anyway, it's End-of-life is going next year.

Comment: @mike it's a school project but thank you for the information.

Comment: Could you try prefix the test route with `/web` to be `/web/test`?

Comment: @mike Who's said that Silex will be stopped the next year? [**The official website**](https://silex.symfony.com/) has no any mention about that!

Comment: Like that ? `$routes->get('/web/test', 'Sources\\Controllers\\ExempleController::test');` Still the same error.

Comment: @SaidbakR this was announced on latest SymfonyCon. Silex is obsolete since Flex is coming out

Comment: @mike I think this is meant by [*version 1.3*](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/1.3/) not current version 2.0